# Unable to see items in publishing queue

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1.  We have a user who is having access to 2 publications, he can publish the pages from those publications, but when he check published items in publishing queue he can't see any item in publishing queue (though he published number of items).
Can anyone let us know what is going wrong?

Few part of Transport Log attached.

```
2013-01-03 12:34:43,221 DEBUG DestinationController - Transports in progress: 1
2013-01-03 12:34:43,237 DEBUG ParallelDestinationWorker - Waiting for transport result for: tcm:0-283176-66560
2013-01-03 12:34:43,252 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-03 12:34:43,252 DEBUG TransportSender - Starting sending transportPackage: D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-283176-66560.Content.zip
2013-01-03 12:34:43,689 DEBUG HTTPSTransportConnector - Successfully transport content to destination: http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx
2013-01-03 12:34:43,689 DEBUG TransportSender - Sending D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-283176-66560.Content.zip to destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q== completed.
2013-01-03 12:34:43,705 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:34:43,705 DEBUG ParallelDestinationWorker - Received item from transport destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:34:43,736 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2013-01-03 12:34:43,736 DEBUG DestinationController - Finalizing transport for transaction: tcm:0-283176-66560 on destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:34:43,736 DEBUG DestinationController - Transports in progress: 0
2013-01-03 12:34:43,736 DEBUG StepTransport - Transport was succesfully completed for transaction:tcm:0-283176-66560
2013-01-03 12:34:43,736 INFO  StepPhaseOneCommit - Transport has no transaction control, not sending commit/rollback commands for transaction: tcm:0-283176-66560
2013-01-03 12:34:43,736 INFO  StepPrepare - Finalizing/cleaning transaction: tcm:0-283176-66560
2013-01-03 12:34:47,449 DEBUG DestinationController - Checking destination for transport metadata
2013-01-03 12:34:47,449 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-03 12:34:47,480 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:34:47,480 DEBUG DestinationController - Starting polling on destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:34:47,480 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-03 12:34:47,979 DEBUG DestinationController - Found notification for transaction: tcm:0-283176-66560
2013-01-03 12:34:47,979 DEBUG DestinationController - New deployer endpoint information received for transaction: tcm:0-283176-66560 and destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:34:48,010 DEBUG DestinationController - Polling attempt 1 for transaction: tcm:0-283176-66560 on destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:34:48,010 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:34:53,018 DEBUG DestinationController - Checking destination for transport metadata
2013-01-03 12:34:53,018 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-03 12:34:53,034 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:34:53,034 DEBUG DestinationController - Starting polling on destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:34:53,049 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-03 12:34:53,065 DEBUG DestinationController - Found notification for transaction: tcm:0-283176-66560
2013-01-03 12:34:53,065 DEBUG DestinationController - New deployer endpoint information received for transaction: tcm:0-283176-66560 and destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:34:53,081 DEBUG DestinationController - Polling attempt 2 for transaction: tcm:0-283176-66560 on destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:34:53,081 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:34:58,104 DEBUG DestinationController - Checking destination for transport metadata
2013-01-03 12:34:58,104 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-03 12:34:58,119 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:34:58,119 DEBUG DestinationController - Starting polling on destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:34:58,119 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-03 12:34:58,135 DEBUG DestinationController - Found notification for transaction: tcm:0-283176-66560
2013-01-03 12:34:58,135 DEBUG DestinationController - New deployer endpoint information received for transaction: tcm:0-283176-66560 and destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:34:58,151 INFO  DestinationController - All Deployer endpoints have completed, setting transaction to completed for: tcm:0-283176-66560
2013-01-03 12:34:58,151 DEBUG RollingStateRetriever - Unable to read transport state file, not adding to summary batch
2013-01-03 12:34:58,166 DEBUG DestinationController - Removing notification task for destination iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q== for transaction: tcm:0-283176-66560
2013-01-03 12:34:58,166 DEBUG DestinationController - Polling attempt 3 for transaction: tcm:0-283176-66560 on destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:34:58,166 INFO  DestinationController - RemoteEndpoint: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q== completed deployment handling, deleting state file: tcm_0-283176-66560.state.xml
2013-01-03 12:34:58,166 DEBUG HTTPSTransportConnector - Doing remove operation on remote HTTP(s) destination: http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx?fileName=tcm_0-283176-66560.state.xml&action=remove
2013-01-03 12:34:58,182 INFO  HTTPSTransportConnector - Deleted file at remote HTTP(s) destination: tcm_0-283176-66560.state.xml was success: true
2013-01-03 12:34:58,182 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:36:02,939 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Purging connector: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] idle for: 64757
2013-01-03 12:39:37,131 DEBUG DestinationControllerMonitor - Cleaning up destination controllers.
2013-01-03 12:39:37,131 DEBUG DestinationController - Idle(ms): 278965, Transports: 0, Notifications: true
2013-01-03 12:40:23,526 DEBUG TransportService - Starting handing of a transaction
2013-01-03 12:40:23,541 INFO  TransactionProcessor - No existing transport transaction information for: tcm:0-283177-66560 creating new transaction state
2013-01-03 12:40:23,541 DEBUG TransactionHeader - Writing[TransactionHeader transactionId=tcm:0-283177-66560 control=COMMIT] to C:\temp\tcm_0-283177-66560.Content\transaction.xml
2013-01-03 12:40:23,541 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2013-01-03 12:40:23,572 INFO  TransportService - Starting transport handling of transaction: tcm:0-283177-66560
2013-01-03 12:40:23,572 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2013-01-03 12:40:23,572 INFO  TransportPoolManager - Creating a new TransportPoolConnector, because no available connectors in connection pool
2013-01-03 12:40:23,572 DEBUG TransportPoolConnector - Configuring TransportPoolConnector.
2013-01-03 12:40:23,572 DEBUG HTTPSTransportConnector - Authentication information supplied, setting basic credentials
2013-01-03 12:40:23,572 DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Starting retrieving active transactions at destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:40:23,604 DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Found 0 transactions in progress and 0 waiting transactions.
2013-01-03 12:40:23,604 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:40:23,604 INFO  DestinationController - Transaction fits inside current window, proceeding transaction: tcm:0-283177-66560
2013-01-03 12:40:23,604 DEBUG TransactionManager - Destination is available for transport: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:40:23,604 DEBUG TransactionManager - All destinations are available for transport of transaction: tcm:0-283177-66560
2013-01-03 12:40:23,619 INFO  ZipWorker - Preparing TransportPackage for id: tcm:0-283177-66560
2013-01-03 12:40:23,619 DEBUG ZipWorker - Zipping Transportpackage: c:\Temp\tcm_0-283177-66560.Content
2013-01-03 12:40:24,087 DEBUG ZipWorker - Zipping has been completed for transaction: tcm:0-283177-66560
2013-01-03 12:40:24,087 DEBUG StepPrepare - Zipping has been completed successfully for transaction: tcm:0-283177-66560
2013-01-03 12:40:24,087 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2013-01-03 12:40:24,118 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2013-01-03 12:40:24,134 DEBUG DestinationController - Transports in progress: 1
2013-01-03 12:40:24,134 DEBUG ParallelDestinationWorker - Waiting for transport result for: tcm:0-283177-66560
2013-01-03 12:40:24,150 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-03 12:40:24,150 DEBUG TransportSender - Starting sending transportPackage: D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-283177-66560.Content.zip
2013-01-03 12:40:24,508 DEBUG HTTPSTransportConnector - Successfully transport content to destination: http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx
2013-01-03 12:40:24,508 DEBUG TransportSender - Sending D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-283177-66560.Content.zip to destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q== completed.
2013-01-03 12:40:24,540 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:40:24,540 DEBUG ParallelDestinationWorker - Received item from transport destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:40:24,555 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2013-01-03 12:40:24,555 DEBUG DestinationController - Finalizing transport for transaction: tcm:0-283177-66560 on destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:40:24,555 DEBUG DestinationController - Transports in progress: 0
2013-01-03 12:40:24,555 DEBUG StepTransport - Transport was succesfully completed for transaction:tcm:0-283177-66560
2013-01-03 12:40:24,555 INFO  StepPhaseOneCommit - Transport has no transaction control, not sending commit/rollback commands for transaction: tcm:0-283177-66560
2013-01-03 12:40:24,555 INFO  StepPrepare - Finalizing/cleaning transaction: tcm:0-283177-66560
2013-01-03 12:40:28,720 DEBUG DestinationController - Checking destination for transport metadata
2013-01-03 12:40:28,720 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-03 12:40:28,736 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:40:28,736 DEBUG DestinationController - Starting polling on destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:40:28,736 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-03 12:40:28,752 DEBUG DestinationController - Found notification for transaction: tcm:0-283177-66560
2013-01-03 12:40:28,752 DEBUG DestinationController - New deployer endpoint information received for transaction: tcm:0-283177-66560 and destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:40:28,767 INFO  DestinationController - All Deployer endpoints have completed, setting transaction to completed for: tcm:0-283177-66560
2013-01-03 12:40:28,798 DEBUG DestinationController - Removing notification task for destination iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q== for transaction: tcm:0-283177-66560
2013-01-03 12:40:28,798 DEBUG DestinationController - Polling attempt 1 for transaction: tcm:0-283177-66560 on destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:40:28,814 INFO  DestinationController - RemoteEndpoint: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q== completed deployment handling, deleting state file: tcm_0-283177-66560.state.xml
2013-01-03 12:40:28,814 DEBUG HTTPSTransportConnector - Doing remove operation on remote HTTP(s) destination: http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx?fileName=tcm_0-283177-66560.state.xml&action=remove
2013-01-03 12:40:28,830 INFO  HTTPSTransportConnector - Deleted file at remote HTTP(s) destination: tcm_0-283177-66560.state.xml was success: true
2013-01-03 12:40:28,830 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:41:33,461 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Purging connector: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] idle for: 64631
2013-01-03 12:42:14,645 DEBUG TransportService - Starting handing of a transaction
2013-01-03 12:42:14,645 INFO  TransactionProcessor - No existing transport transaction information for: tcm:0-283178-66560 creating new transaction state
2013-01-03 12:42:14,661 DEBUG TransactionHeader - Writing[TransactionHeader transactionId=tcm:0-283178-66560 control=COMMIT] to C:\temp\tcm_0-283178-66560.Content\transaction.xml
2013-01-03 12:42:14,661 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2013-01-03 12:42:14,723 INFO  TransportService - Starting transport handling of transaction: tcm:0-283178-66560
2013-01-03 12:42:14,723 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2013-01-03 12:42:14,723 INFO  TransportPoolManager - Creating a new TransportPoolConnector, because no available connectors in connection pool
2013-01-03 12:42:14,723 DEBUG TransportPoolConnector - Configuring TransportPoolConnector.
2013-01-03 12:42:14,723 DEBUG HTTPSTransportConnector - Authentication information supplied, setting basic credentials
2013-01-03 12:42:14,723 DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Starting retrieving active transactions at destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:42:14,754 DEBUG DestinationProgressWorker - Found 0 transactions in progress and 0 waiting transactions.
2013-01-03 12:42:14,754 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:42:14,754 INFO  DestinationController - Transaction fits inside current window, proceeding transaction: tcm:0-283178-66560
2013-01-03 12:42:14,754 DEBUG TransactionManager - Destination is available for transport: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:42:14,754 DEBUG TransactionManager - All destinations are available for transport of transaction: tcm:0-283178-66560
2013-01-03 12:42:14,770 INFO  ZipWorker - Preparing TransportPackage for id: tcm:0-283178-66560
2013-01-03 12:42:14,770 DEBUG ZipWorker - Zipping Transportpackage: c:\Temp\tcm_0-283178-66560.Content
2013-01-03 12:42:14,973 DEBUG ZipWorker - Zipping has been completed for transaction: tcm:0-283178-66560
2013-01-03 12:42:14,973 DEBUG StepPrepare - Zipping has been completed successfully for transaction: tcm:0-283178-66560
2013-01-03 12:42:14,973 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2013-01-03 12:42:15,020 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2013-01-03 12:42:15,035 DEBUG DestinationController - Transports in progress: 1
2013-01-03 12:42:15,035 DEBUG ParallelDestinationWorker - Waiting for transport result for: tcm:0-283178-66560
2013-01-03 12:42:15,051 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-03 12:42:15,051 DEBUG TransportSender - Starting sending transportPackage: D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-283178-66560.Content.zip
2013-01-03 12:42:15,191 DEBUG HTTPSTransportConnector - Successfully transport content to destination: http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx
2013-01-03 12:42:15,191 DEBUG TransportSender - Sending D:\Tridion\bin\transactions\tcm_0-283178-66560.Content.zip to destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q== completed.
2013-01-03 12:42:15,207 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:42:15,207 DEBUG ParallelDestinationWorker - Received item from transport destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:42:15,222 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2013-01-03 12:42:15,222 DEBUG DestinationController - Finalizing transport for transaction: tcm:0-283178-66560 on destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:42:15,222 DEBUG DestinationController - Transports in progress: 0
2013-01-03 12:42:15,222 DEBUG StepTransport - Transport was succesfully completed for transaction:tcm:0-283178-66560
2013-01-03 12:42:15,222 INFO  StepPhaseOneCommit - Transport has no transaction control, not sending commit/rollback commands for transaction: tcm:0-283178-66560
2013-01-03 12:42:15,222 INFO  StepPrepare - Finalizing/cleaning transaction: tcm:0-283178-66560
2013-01-03 12:42:18,998 DEBUG DestinationController - Checking destination for transport metadata
2013-01-03 12:42:18,998 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-03 12:42:19,013 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:42:19,013 DEBUG DestinationController - Starting polling on destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:42:19,013 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2013-01-03 12:42:19,044 DEBUG DestinationController - Found notification for transaction: tcm:0-283178-66560
2013-01-03 12:42:19,044 DEBUG DestinationController - New deployer endpoint information received for transaction: tcm:0-283178-66560 and destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:42:19,060 INFO  DestinationController - All Deployer endpoints have completed, setting transaction to completed for: tcm:0-283178-66560
2013-01-03 12:42:19,107 DEBUG DestinationController - Removing notification task for destination iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q== for transaction: tcm:0-283178-66560
2013-01-03 12:42:19,107 DEBUG DestinationController - Polling attempt 1 for transaction: tcm:0-283178-66560 on destination: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q==
2013-01-03 12:42:19,107 INFO  DestinationController - RemoteEndpoint: iH1DJ7u5t1piMKRZi9OS0Q== completed deployment handling, deleting state file: tcm_0-283178-66560.state.xml
2013-01-03 12:42:19,107 DEBUG HTTPSTransportConnector - Doing remove operation on remote HTTP(s) destination: http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx?fileName=tcm_0-283178-66560.state.xml&action=remove
2013-01-03 12:42:19,122 INFO  HTTPSTransportConnector - Deleted file at remote HTTP(s) destination: tcm_0-283178-66560.state.xml was success: true
2013-01-03 12:42:19,122 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Connector is registered for reuse: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1
2013-01-03 12:43:23,629 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Purging connector: HTTPS[Password[******], UserName[TridionAppUser], URL[http://10.97.12.24:20000/httpupload.aspx]] idle for: 64507
2013-01-03 12:44:37,136 DEBUG DestinationControllerMonitor - Cleaning up destination controllers.
2013-01-03 12:44:37,136 DEBUG DestinationController - Idle(ms): 138029, Transports: 0, Notifications: true
2013-01-03 12:49:37,140 DEBUG DestinationControllerMonitor - Cleaning up destination controllers.
2013-01-03 12:49:37,140 DEBUG DestinationController - Idle(ms): 438033, Transports: 0, Notifications: true
2013-01-03 12:54:37,144 DEBUG DestinationControllerMonitor - Cleaning up destination controllers.
2013-01-03 12:54:37,144 DEBUG DestinationController - Idle(ms): 738037, Transports: 0, Notifications: true
```

Comment: If it reaches transport then it _must_ show in the queue. I don't see errors in this log, was the file deployed? It looks like the original issue (not showing in queue) and this log are unrelated...

Answer (score 2):

Did it actually publish anything? You can send things to the queue that result in no publish action being needed (for instance, select a Structure Group with no Pages, Publish = nothing to publish).

Comment: We have a login.aspx page when administrator user publishes this page he can see login.aspx in publishing queue, but when non administrator uer publishes it he/she can't see any transaction in publishing queue.

Comment: Enable publisher logging (in the MMC) or run the Publisher in debug mode to figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

If an administrative user logs in and sets the Publish Queue to show all transactions, do they see the Publish job from the non-admin user?

If the transactions from the non-admin user are not visible to the admin user, then follow Nuno's advice on running the Publisher in debug / logging - it's likely nothing is actually being sent for publishing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like package is reaching to the deployer and then it is roll-backed the operation.

It might caused due to size limit on http upload, I guess.